# Swift: Share Auth state between apps

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Inside my app the user can sign in with Apple, Google, Facebook and Email using `Firebase`. I also have a `Share Extension` and I would like to share the `auth-state` from the Main-App so I can also call `Auth.auth.currentUser` inside my `ShareExtension` so the user can access `Cloud-Firestore`.

Now I know there is this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on) provided by **Firebase**. However I am not sure about **Step 2**:

```
do {
   try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("TEAMID.com.example.group1")
} catch let error as NSError {
   print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
}
```

Where exactly do I have to call this?

**Edit:**

**Main App:**

[image]

**Share Extension:**
[image]

**Update:**

It is throwing this `error` when calling the code above before `signIn`:

> Error changing user access group: %@ Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (-34018), NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered}

Comment: Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (and similar methods in extensions) I guess. Just after `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Comment: @DimaRostopira tried that but when calling `let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` inside my `Share Extension` it is always `nil`...

Comment: Make sure you use correct group id and enabled app groups for extension

Comment: @DimaRostopira what exactly do you mean by *correct group id* ?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you can see the flow you have to follow. First, anywhere in the app you have the login process you have to add this lines of code:

```
do {
  try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("TEAMID.com.example.group1")
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
}
```

You can add them in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the delegate, but you can use it wherever you want.

In the other app you have to add the same code. The two apps have to have the same Access Group, right?

Then in one of the app, you have to execute this sentence:

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { result, error in
  // User signed in
}
```

You can put it just after the first code above. Then you will be able to access the user in both apps like this:

```
var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

Comment: by *the same Access Group* , you mean App Group or Keychain Group? btw, I updated my question

Comment: I mean, this part "TEAMID.com.example.group1", must be the same for both apps. And when you make a login in any app, you will be able to access to Auth.auth() full content, so you can check user, state, status, etc...

Comment: Did you delete the app from device when changing groups and made a clear build folder before rebuild? It is a silly question but sometimes it is the problem.

Comment: did you have a look at my updated question ? The error message ? I dont get it...

Comment: Well, the error is because the configuration of the keychain access, I think it is better follow this guide than me trying to explain :) Take a look to this guide dude: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224107/discussion-between-chris-and-wazowski).